# Is it possible to execute a script in android when the user exit the app / kill the process?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

is it possible to execute a script in android when the user exit the app / kill the process?

I mean when a script isnt done yet and the user kills the process, the script stops right? Is it possible to force the script to run till the end?

Or is there a way to execute a script when the user kills the process?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you can't dectect when app is killed or uninstalled. When app is killed, all the processes and services are killed. So, the answer is no.

Comment: is there no way to create a own process or someting?

Comment: There isn't. The closest thing is implement `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` but it is specific for activities, but not for the application itself. Hope it helps

Comment: im sorry but there is a way. I solved this with the android Service class. I make a new prozess and even when the prozess of the app is killed / destroyed, my Service runs.

Comment: Can you tell me why? How have you killed your app?

Comment: Im killing the process of the app, i dont uninstall it. A lot of apps use the service class to keep functions running while the app is closed